# import declarations may only appear at top level of a module and disallowed MIME type

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm trying to load a script that includes an import statement, but Firefox shows the "import declarations..." error in the console. The import in my script looks something like this:

`import { foo } from './path/to/js/file';`

I can get rid of this error by including `type="module"` as an attribute of the script tag in my HTML, but then I get a different error in the console:

"Loading module from “http://localhost:8000/path/to/js/file” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”)."

It also shows a `404` in the console for the script I'm trying to import.

Interestingly, I can get rid of both of these by appending `.js` to my import statement:

`import { foo } from './path/to/js/file.js';`

But since `file.js` is part of a larger library with its own import statements, all subsequent import statements raise MIME type errors and 404s.

I'm using Django as my backend framework and the application is in a docker container.

What am I doing wrong?